# Overlay a WPF window with a native window and enable some user controls being still above it

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, sdl

I have a WPF app and a SDL windows app, both used in fullscreen. I would like to host the SDL window inside the WPF app, but still having the ability to show some WPF user controls above it.

The SDL Windows app is launched by the WPF app and I am able to overlay it using the following method:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);
```

So, my SDL window appears to be "integrated" to my WPF app by overlapping it. But I have a WPF user control I still would like to have on top.

To be more explicit, it's a SDL game with a WPF joystick control on top of the game, something like this :

[image: GUI]

How can I succeed such a thing?

Comment: I think : it is not possible with WPF, use Winform.

Comment: Yeah I'm going with a WindowsFormsHost control and call SetParent with the control's handle as param.